# How to change image path using .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, path, url-rewriting

I have two websites e.g.,

```
www.example1.com
www.example2.com
```

example1 is already up and has all the images I need to put in my example2 website.

i want to get all images from example1 to put in my example2 website e.g.,

Original Path - www.example1.com/media/img/image1.jpg

Below url in showing original image but only change only new path

New path - www.example2.com/media/img/image1.jpg

Comment: I think you have no sense what a .htaccess is, and what you can do with it - or I don't understand your question the right way.

Comment: `get this image and put in

www.example2.com/media/img/image1.jpg` You need to clarify this line further.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand it right you should use this in htaccess on www.example1.com/:

```
Redirect /media/img/(.*) http://www.example2.com/media/img/$1
```

But validate this please, becouse i do not know if the syntax is 100% correct.